# Subprocess.run timeout not killing subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, ubuntu-20.04

I'm currently on `python-3.8.10` on `Ubuntu 20` with the following code.  And despite every attempt the timeout does not seem to work. I'm unsure if I am inputing the text wrong?

```
    cmd = 'ebook-convert "%s" "%s"' % (filename, outfile)
    process = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=77400)

    try:
        ConversionFile.set_to_finished(options.get('uuid'))

        if process.stderr and "error" in process.stderr.decode("utf-8"):
            return {'error': process.stderr.decode("utf-8")}
        return [outfile]
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Yet the program runs longer than the timeout and never gets killed

Comment: That's 21.5 hours! I just want to verify that the desired timeout is 77400 seconds.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Correct, most convert under that, but occasional there are some that go on for days.  So would rather just kill it after day.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with a sleep or a spinlock for `cmd`, using a shorter timeout of course. Any chance this code is wrapped in a `try/except` and it's catching the `TimeoutExpired`?

Comment: I don't know if it affects the problem, but there's no reason to use a shell for this.

Comment: @MichaelRuth That shouldn't matter. It catches the exception internally so it can kill the child process, then it reraises it.

Comment: I just updated the code for the entire block.  I can't figure out why it does not kill it.  It also does not kill it when the command is ffmpeg.

Comment: Does it work if you use `cmd = ['ebook-convert', filename, outfile]` and get rid of `shell=True`?

Comment: @Barmar I will update code and report back on the server if some hang and don't get killed

Comment: Try running without a shell. The timeout will kill the intermediate shell process but not ebook-convert.

Comment: This answer may explain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: due to the filename being a django object sometimes and other times a string.  The `shell=True` seems to be required if not I get fails just alone due to filename issues.  So given Michael Ruth's SO answer, I have added `"exec "` to all the commands and will report if that fixes it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the filename thing... its a django object who's string representation is okay? Then `cmd = ['ebook-convert', str(filename), outfile]` with `shell=False` may be what you want.

Comment: @tdelaney As I have started to migrate the functions, would like to point out that the str(filename) fixe's the issue so it runs without shell=True as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `exec`  command to the subprocess commands worked based on this stack overflow answer [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

It was also noted in the comments that another solution is taking out `shell=True` and changing up the commands to be in a list instead of a string.  Although this may be correct, there are too many different functions in the actual file and I posted a simplified command of one of the almost hundred different subprocesses.

Hence, why went with just simply adding the `exec`  command to each subprocess.